# how to fix this $scope to show in HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

i have $scope in function but this $scope cant show in html How To make it show ?

> this code in fucntion

```
$scope.checkBrach = function(index) {
    console.log($scope.dataBranch[index]);
    $scope.branchCode = $scope.dataBranch[index].branch_code;
}
```

> this code in HTML and {{branchCode}} dont show data for me

×
                    รายชื่อสาขา
                
                
                    
                        
                            
                                
                                    
                                    
                                    choose
                                
                            
                            
                                
                                    {{i.branch_code}}
                                    {{i.branch_name}}
                                    
                                        
                                            build
                                        
                                        
                                            delete
                                        
                                    
                                
                            
                        
                    
                
                
                    
                        Close
                        OK

```
<div aria-hidden="true" class="modal fade" id="delete-branch" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" ng-controller="contestCtrl">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-xs">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-heading">
                <a class="modal-close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
                <h2 class="modal-title">Modal Title</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-inner">
                <p>
                    <strong>{{branchCode}}</strong>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <p class="text-right">
                    <button class="btn btn-flat btn-alt" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">Close</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-flat btn-alt" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">OK</button>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you provide plunker

Comment: Is the `checkBrach` function in the controller invoked?

Comment: function getBranch() {
        $http.post("api/getBranch.php").success(function(data) {
            $scope.dataBranch = data;
        });
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to set the value for `$scope.branchCode` you must run the function `$scope.checkBrach` because the scope variable branchCode is being created inside that function or you could define your variable at the top of your controller like `$scope.branchCode = "xyz branch code"`.

Comment: im use ng-click for run $scope.checkBrach before to show this data.

Comment: ng-click="checkBrach($index);